# How to specify which view controller you are preparing for with Swift's prepareForSegue function?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue

So I have multiple buttons on one view segue'ing to other views. I have the function `prepareForSegue()` at the bottom of my code preparing one segue, however the app crashes when I use another segue on the view, even if it doesn't need any preparing.
I think that the problem is that all of the segues use the `prepareForSegue()` function, however the storyboard ID is different than the view it is transitioning to.
Is there any way to specify a `prepareForSegue()` function for each separate segue on the same view?
Code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let theVC: ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
    theVC.receivedString = "true"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your prepareForSegue you should use a condition to check **segue identifier** like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "yourSegueToAnyController")
        {
           //do code for specific viewController
        }

    }
```